# $F(x- 2 \sqrt{x})=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $F(x+ 2 \sqrt{x})= x+ 4 \sqrt{x}+ 4 $, so $F(x- 2 \sqrt{x})=?$

**Solution:** Let $x+2\sqrt{x}=t$, with $t\geq -1$, so, $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{t+1}-1$.
$F(x+2\sqrt{x})=(\sqrt{x}+2)^2\Leftrightarrow F(t)=(\sqrt{t+1}+1)^2$.
Let $x-2\sqrt{x}=p$, with $p\geq 1$, and choose $t:=p$.
Hence, $F(p)=F(x-2\sqrt{x})=(\sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x}+1}+1)^2=(|\sqrt{x}-1|+1)^2$

If it were in the reals, would that result too?

Comment: what do you mean by "if it were in the reals"? Where have you been working?

Comment: @Gae.S. This question does not have a domain defined in the statement, if it were set of the real would remain the same answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:[0,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ be the map $x+2\sqrt x$. Its image is the set of all $t\in\Bbb R$ such that the equation $u^2+2u-t$ has a non-negative solution. I.e., the set $[0,\infty)$. Therefore, we may switch to considering $g:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ and $g^{-1}(x)=(\sqrt{x+1}-1)^2$. Therefore, we know that $\left. F\right\rvert_{[0,\infty)}= F\circ g\circ g^{-1}$, i.e. that for all $x\ge0$, \begin{align}F(x)&=(\sqrt{x+1}-1)^2+4\lvert \sqrt{x+1}-1\rvert+4=\\&=x+1-2\sqrt{x+1}+1+4\sqrt{x+1}-4+4=\\ &=x+2\sqrt{x+1}+2\end{align}

We know *nothing* about what $F$ does for negative values of $x$, and there isn't sufficient information to know it. Let's call $h:[0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$, $h(x)=x-2\sqrt x$. All we can do is look for information about $\left.h\right\rvert_{h^{-1}[0,\infty)}$. Notice that $$h^{-1}[0,\infty)=\{x\ge 0\,:\, x-2\sqrt x\ge 0\}=\{0\}\cup[4,\infty)$$

Therefore we may deduce that for all $x$ such that either $x=0$ or $x\ge4$ \begin{align}F(x-2\sqrt x)&=x-2\sqrt x+2\sqrt{x-2\sqrt x+1}+2=\\&=x-2\sqrt x+2\left\lvert \sqrt x-1\right\rvert+2=\\&=\left( \sqrt x-1\right)^2+2\left\lvert \sqrt x-1\right\rvert+1=\left(\left\lvert \sqrt x-1\right\rvert+1\right)^2\end{align}